# How to convert a JTextField String to java.sql.date Date

Tags: sql, string, date, jtextfield

A frequently asked question (also for me) was: How to convert a simple String from e.g. a `JTextField` to a `java.sql.date` `Date` - to insert some GUI-User-Input as **correctly formatted Date** into a table through a Prepared Statement.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write a new convert-specified Class, which has this option.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class convertText {
    public java.sql.Date formatStringToSQLDate(String strDate) throws Exception{
        Date utilDate = new Date(); //DateFormat
        SimpleDateFormat dfFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy"); // parse string into a DATE format      
        utilDate = dfFormat.parse(strDate); // convert a util.Date to milliseconds via its getTime() method         
        long time = utilDate.getTime(); // get the long value of java.sql.Date 
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(time);
        return sqlDate;   
    }
}
```

Afterwards, to use it like this.

```
Connection dp = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + Filepath + Filename);
Statement stat = dp.createStatement();
String sql = "INSERT INTO user_table (Name, Birth) VALUES(?, ?)"; //statement as string
PreparedStatement pstmt = dp.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setString(1, textFieldVorname.getText()); //replaces the first '?'
pstmt.setDate(2, Date.formatStringToSQLDate(textFieldGeburtsdatum.getText())); //replaces the second '?'
pstmt.executeUpdate(); //executes the insert-query
```